# Storing pointer as long "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

Tags: c

I am trying to write the value of a variable with some pointer arithmetic (not shown here for clarity), but I am stuck trying to write the base value to the variable intended to store the pointer.

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct st_VARS
{ /* struct VARS */
      unsigned long A;
      unsigned long B;
      unsigned long C;
      unsigned long D;
      unsigned long E;
};
#define VARS (*(struct st_VARS *)0xFFFFABF0)

struct st_MAPS
{
      unsigned char VV[64];
      unsigned long WW[64];
      unsigned char XX[64];
      unsigned char YY[64];
      unsigned char ZZ[256];
};
#define MAPS ((struct st_MAPS *)0x7DA00)

int main(){
    //VARS.C = &MAPS->YY[0];  // this is what I'm try to do
    char *p;
    p = &MAPS->YY[0];
    unsigned long s;
    s = p;
    //VARS.C = s; //this doesn't work either
    printf("Address of pointer p: %p\n", p); //this prints as 64 bits, can I limit it to 32?
    printf("Content of pointer p: %d\n", *p);
    printf("Value of s: %X\n", s);
    printf("Address of VARS.C: %X\n", &VARS.C);
    //printf("Value of VARS.C: %X\n", VARS.C); //this doesn't print, assume because my PC is not the target hardware
}
```

Comment: `s = p;` is making integer from pointer without a cast. Your title looks bad because it attracts our (at least mine) attention there.

Comment: Tip: `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are better types than `unsigned long` to store a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

C warns you when you implicitly cast a pointer to a number. To fix this, just explicitly cast it:

```c
unsigned long s = (unsigned long) p;
```